# Texture Painting - wrap brush to mesh?

Tags: texture-painting

Perhaps its that I haven't used the right phrases but I haven't been able to find not only a solution to my issue, I haven't been able to see the issue raised at all.

In texture paint mode the paint is projected from the viewport through the brush. This has been an entirely unworkable process for me, Every stroke I make has unintended consequences - jagged edges, projected silhouettes... Instead of projecting the painted area based brush bound by the view, is there a way for the brush to essentially be anchored to the topology of the mesh, such that the brush literally serves to isolate geometry to work upon, rather than project from the view axis onto the mesh.

A line drawn from left to right, slight feathering
[image: front view]

Hitting the edge of geometry from one view always leads to sharp, hideous edges etc etc etc
[image: angled view]

Like I say, I haven't seen anyone else post about this. I don't understand why, it's not workable for making a base coat never mind finer details

...appreciations and props to whoever points out the inevitably obvious setting I've missed, or first git gud post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Project Paint settings to get around this - by default, Occlude, Cull and Normal are all on, as well as a 2 pixel bleed. You can uncheck these like I show in the picture, and then your paint will paint through the mesh all the way like a blade - and if you want to only do some of it, you can use the Face Selection masking in the header window, right next to the drawtype icon. [image: unoccluded on left, occluded on right]

Comment: I appreciate the response Craig.

In the end using occlude/cull with strategic view placement and a lot of smearing and softening got the gradients I wanted. Again, softening and smearing after masking went a long way to getting the results I wanted. Still, I would prefer if the brush rather than projecting paint was linked to the topology, much as I can imagine the issues that may present for the devs. 

Still, work with what you've got, doesn't dissuade me from sticking with Blender.

Comment: You can use a gradient in the Fill brush, and then pull a line perpendicular to the edge of your intended stroke. I use gradient fills all the time like this, I just wish they responded to the brush mask. Have to use the Mask tool for that.